# How can I change a variable in ASM, nothing I do seems to work?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, reference, x86, inline-assembly

So here is my code, I am trying to set a_character to ecx, my encrypted letter. i dont get any errors but the variable will not change.

```
void get_char(char& a_character)
{
  a_character = (char)_getwche();
  if (a_character == '\r' || a_character == '\n')  // allow the enter key to work as the terminating character too
  {
    a_character = dollarchar;
  }

  __asm
  {

      cmp     ecx, '[';
      jb      RANGE_C;
      jge     RESUME;

  RANGE_C:   cmp     ecx, '@';
      ja      LOWER;
      jle     RESUME;

  LOWER:     ADD    ecx, 32
      JMP    RESUME;

RESUME:
  mov         a_character, ecx

    
      

  }


}
```

Comment: `char &a_character` probably works like a pointer from asm.  It might be easier to return a `char` by value.

Comment: Also, `ecx` is not even set to anything, and a `char` is 1 byte not 4.